# Calling a def from another def in the same Class

Tags: python, function

I have the next code:

```
class UserMethods():
    @style.queue
    def checkAuth(db, user, password):
       self.addUser(db, user, password)

    @style.queue
    def addUser(db, user, password):
        salt = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [str(random.randint(0, 9)) for i in range(0, 5)])
        h = sha1(salt + password)
        password = salt + h.hexdigest()

        c = db.c
        c.execute('SELECT name FROM users WHERE name=?', (user, ))
        if c.fetchone() is not None:
            c.execute('UPDATE users SET password=? WHERE name=?', (password, user))
        else:
            c.execute('INSERT INTO users (name, password) VALUES (?, ?)', (user, password))
```

I don't know what is the purpose of @style.queue but I think that this is not relevant.

But the part of `self.addUser(db, user, password)` is not working for me. How can I call **addUser** inside **checkAuth**  ??

The errors are:

NameError: global name 'addUser' is not defined
Database Error @ checkAuth ('lroca', 'asgard*123+') {} global name 'addUser' is not defined

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *not working*?

Comment: You're not passing `self` to `checkAuth`... (or `addUser` for that matter.)

Comment: What is `@style.queue` doing? Instance methods should take `self` as their first argument.

Answer (score 2):

The comments from Cameron and Wooble are correct. To fix the immediate problem, add `self` as the first argument of your instance methods. Here is the updated code:

```
class UserMethods():
    @style.queue
    def checkAuth(self, db, user, password):
       self.addUser(db, user, password)

    @style.queue
    def addUser(self, db, user, password):
        salt = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [str(random.randint(0, 9)) for i in range(0, 5)])
        h = sha1(salt + password)
        password = salt + h.hexdigest()

        c = db.c
        c.execute('SELECT name FROM users WHERE name=?', (user, ))
        if c.fetchone() is not None:
            c.execute('UPDATE users SET password=? WHERE name=?', (password, user))
        else:
            c.execute('INSERT INTO users (name, password) VALUES (?, ?)', (user, password))
```

As a side note: it appears this program may accept arbitrary input for the `user` and `password` and thus may be vulnerable to a [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: I tried this and this is the error:

self.result = self.f(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: checkAuth() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
Database Error @ checkAuth (name, password) {} checkAuth() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)